# Windows 10 black vertical line on screen

Tags: windows, windows-10

I upgraded my Lenovo G50 laptop to Windows 10 a few months ago. After some days of usage, I observed a black vertical line in the middle of my laptop's screen when I woke up my laptop from sleep mode. I thought it was my screen's problem but it wasn't. The line only appeared on my desktop screen. It disappeared after a reboot. But now it frequently appears, and I have no other option other than rebooting my laptop. I didn't have this problem with Windows 8.1. Is anyone facing the same problem? Do you have any suggestions about how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Sometimes a sign of a dying video card..

Comment: More information would be useful. What the laptop's specs are, including the video card would be a start.

Comment: Laptop specs: Intel Celeron Processor N2830 (2.16 GHz 1600MHz 1MB), Intel HD Graphics, 2GB RAM, 15.6" 1366 x 768 display

Answer (score 1):

Experienced same issue when PC brand new Lenovo G50 closed the screen and when it came from sleep it showed. If I opened the battery settings and then closed it, it went away but came back after a few minutes. If I opened a program window it does not show up on the screen but only appears on the desktop background.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Comment: I have lenovo g50 as well.Probably a hardware problem.

Comment: Having same issue with my lenovo G50

Comment: Same in Lenovo Yoga 720 :(

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue... It didn't show until today, though... And it only shows when I have a window open, or open one then minimize it...

However when I press Windows+D for desktop, it disappears...  This is really weird and does not seem to be an issue of display driver... If it is that would be really weird, at least...

If you do Windows+D to go to desktop the black line should disappear.... You shouldn't really be alarmed unless this black line actually overlaps a program is what I would say.

This only seems to be a software issue, and I have only experienced it on my laptop(Lenovo G50-80) and it might be a simple Lenovo software issue of some sort... I do not know of any other fix that is permanent, only the very temporary fix I have already mentioned(Win+D)

After some more research I did indeed solve it... Permanently this time. What I did was that I went into my task manager and started terminating all programs that I could think would cause the issue... After terminating all programs related to Adobe Creativecloud the black line disappeared... I did however close down HotspotShield, but I think that Adobe Creativecloud has something to do with the issue... At least as far as I could tell. Hope it works for you guys too!

-Theodor Frisvold

Answer (score 0):

2017 May
**Answer - Airdroid is causing horizontal background lines (Windows 10)**

Following the lead of T Frisvold's answer, I tried stopping running apps using the task manager. In my case it's AirDroid, which is really too bad, because I like AirDroid running. However when AirDroid is stopped, the 2 horizontal lines near the top and 2 horizontal lines near the bottom of my background screen go away.

Note - you can tell it's not a problem with your screen if you rotate your display (assuming you have, for example, a rotating 2-in-1 laptop - mine is a 2017 Dell Inspiron 5000). The bad lines also rotated from landscape to portrait, showing that it was something wrong with the projected image and not with the display hardware proper.

- Burl

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue - it was a Snip tool that was minimised...if you double click on it it opens
AlSO i just went into the tray icons and right clicked and closed it - took 4 days to figure out